# Can we run index rebuild or reorganize commands from C# winform?

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlcommand

I want to know is it possible to run MS SQL Server index rebuild or reorganize operations from c# winform?

I have a script using rebuild and reorganize. Now I want to run the whole script on the server database with a button click. Is it possible? Or administrative commands can be run only from SSMS?

Comment: Did you try calling this script from your form? What happened?

Comment: No, I just don't know how to do it. @HansKeﬆing

Comment: Try to set up the SqlConnection using an user with enough permissions, for example, use the same user that you are using while running your scripts on the SSMS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, create a `SqlCommand` object and set the `CommandText` appropriately.

Note that identifiers in T-SQL cannot be paramererised which means you may have to use Dynamic SQL (aka Being potentially vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks), so be careful.

For example, to rebuild an index:

```
const String sql = @"
    ALTER INDEX PK_Employee_BusinessEntityID ON HumanResources.Employee REBUILD;
";

using( StringWriter log = new StringWriter() )
using( SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection( connectionString ) )
using( SqlCommand cmd = c.CreateCommand() )
{
    c.InfoMessage += ( s, e ) => log.WriteLine( e.Message );

    await c.OpenAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

    cmd.CommandText = sql;

    await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

    MessageBox.Show( "Done!\r\n" + log.ToString() );
}
```